# Values of variable given the angle is 90 degrees

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Consider the following three points in $\mathbb R^3$: $$P(1, 3, 7),~ Q(−1, 5, 8), ~R(2, 6, 4)$$ and let $a = \overrightarrow {PQ} \ \ \ b= \overrightarrow {PR} \ \ \ c = \overrightarrow {QR}$

Find the values of $~t ~\in \ \mathbb R$ for which $~b + tc~$ is perpendicular to $~a~$.

I have solved it but I got just one value so I am not sure if it's correct.

I calculated a = $\overrightarrow {PQ} = (\vec Q - \vec P) = (-2,2,1),\ \ $ $b = \overrightarrow {PR} = (\vec R - \vec P) = (1, 3, -3)\ \ $ and $c = \overrightarrow {QR} = (\vec R - \vec Q) = (3, 1, -4)$

Then I calculated $b+tc$ as $(1,3,-3) + t(3,1,-4) = (1+3t, 3+t, -3+4t)$

I set $(b+tc).a = 0$ because it's a perpendicular. $$(1+3t, 3+t, -3-4t) \ .\ (-2,2,1) = 0$$ $$-2(1+3t) + 2(3+t) + 1(-3-t)=0$$ $$t=\frac 18$$

I am not sure where I went wrong. I am usually clumsy with my arithmetic operations especially things like $\sqrt {x}$ having two solutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect to get more values? The resulting equation is linear, so there's just the one solution.

Comment: To see why, note that $b+tc$ describes a line in space as $t$ varies over all real numbers. You want to know when (if ever) this line is perpendicular to a certain vector. If such a time exists, then it would happen only once.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Allawonder. I am just paranoid because the question asks for values instead of value(s). I understand now why it should just be a single value.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's mathematical custom to call (possibly singular) things by their plural. It doesn't mean it's necessarily plural; they just want to be inclusive. It's like how we use *or* -- when we say $a$ or $b,$ we mean that both $a$ and $b$ *may* also occur, but it's not necessary that they do. You should get used to this.

Comment: Actually computing the vector $b+tc$ when $t=1/8,$ and taking the dot product with $a,$ I get zero. So you found the correct value, and indeed a good vector diagram of the problem will show there is at most one solution.

Comment: trying my best to catch up with mathematical conventions. thanks for adding to it. really appreciated.

Comment: You left a $4$ out of your penultimate equation.

Answer (score 1):

your last equation is ok. the result wrong. Adding all t you find -5t adding the numbers you get 1
so you have -5t+1=0
just the last step too fast?

Comment: I have recalculated it a few times after reading your comment. Can you please check if you did it right? I seem to get 1/8 each time.

Comment: $t=\frac18$ works out to be a 90 degree angle and $t=-\frac15$ seems to give 76 degrees. thanks for checking out my solution for potential errors and validating my final equations though. means a lot